# Run an executable and giving text file as input using Python on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I could make code but freezes after calling the executable. I have searched on StackOverflow and everywhere else for the answer but with no success.
The question is answered for Linux and the same code I have described below as a sample but it does not work **for windows**. Any input will be of great help.

```
import subprocess
for filename in 'inp1.txt', 'inp2.txt':   #input text files

    with open(filename) as infile, open('result_{}'.format(filename), 'w') as outfile:

       result = subprocess.run([r'C:\Users\Desktop\Python_files\file.exe'], stdin=infile, stdout=outfile) # executable name is file.exe
```

When the code is used for Windows, it freezes. Can anyone give any input?

Comment: can you post the contents of `file.exe`?

Comment: Code looks fine to me. My first guess would be that `file.exe` is hanging.

Comment: I do not have the source code of the file.exe as it is highly confidential. I am using only the executable.

Comment: It might be worth sending stderr somewhere to see if there's any clues in it.

Comment: @TomDalton I think the code freezes in line "result=....." and so even passing stderr could not help

Comment: @Glibdud: The file.exe runs properly when I do it manually with input text file. Only on running with the above code I have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you should try to run it from command prompt and see if its the problem of exe.  if its working in cmd prompt, next thing to look at is whether its waiting for any inputs.

Comment: I am using command prompt and running the above scripts in a file named runner as>> py runner.py

Comment: It waits for input and then freezes